# Online laravel applicatie does not load Elfinder

Tags: jquery-mobile, laravel-4, elfinder

I am using elfinder filemanager to manage the files in laravel. I am also using jquery mobile.

The problem is. Offline the filemanager works. Online it does not.

**This is the first part of my filemanager.php view:**

```
@extends('master')

@section('content2')

{{HTML::style('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css', array('media' => 'screen'))}}
 {{HTML::script('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js', array('type' => 'text/javascript'))}}
 {{HTML::script('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js', array('type' => 'text/javascript'))}}

{{HTML::style('filemanager1/css/elfinder.min.css', array('media' => 'screen'))}}


 {{HTML::script('filemanager1/js/elfinder.min.js', array('type' => 'text/javascript'))}}

<!-- Mac OS X Finder style for jQuery UI smoothness theme (OPTIONAL) -->
{{HTML::style('filemanager1/css/theme.css', array('media' => 'screen'))}}
  {{HTML::script('filemanager1/js/i18n/elfinder.nl.js', array('type' => 'text/javascript'))}}
```

**This is the first part of the master.php where i load my view in:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 {{HTML::script('//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js', array('type' => 'text/javascript'))}}
{{HTML::script('//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js', array('type' => 'text/javascript'))}}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<?php
/// DIT WAREN DE IMPORTS voordat de agenda niet meer werkte.
//echo HTML::script('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js', array('type' => 'text/javascript'));
//echo HTML::script('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js', array('type' => 'text/javascript'));
//echo HTML::script('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js', array('type' => 'text/javascript'));
//echo HTML::script('http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js', array('type' => 'text/javascript'));
?>
<!-- Normal -->
{{HTML::script(asset('js/bootstrap.js'), array('type' => 'text/javascript'))}}
{{HTML::script(asset('js/expandingbox.js'), array('type' => 'text/javascript'))}}
{{HTML::script(asset('js/jscolor/jscolor.js'), array('type' => 'text/javascript'))}}
{{HTML::style(asset('css/bootstrap.css'), array('media' => 'screen'))}}
</head>
```

Also offline i tried to put all my styles and script inside my master file. Then the filemanager stops working too.

---

THIS PART I ADDED LATER

I see the error in the inspector. One of my links:

```
http://dev-certificering.safetyanalyse.nl/public/laravel4_test2/public/filemanager1/css/elfinder.min.css
```

But i can't seem to change anything online.
I changed one of my elfinder imports in my view to:

```
{{HTML::script('filemanager1/js/i18n/elfinder.nl.js??', array('type' => 'text/javascript'))}}
```

When i now open the inspector type ctrl-u i keep seeing the old pages. From a few days ago.
I tried clearing the cash and cookies in chrome. Also tried explorer.

They all show me the old laravel imports. Does laravel have a cash?

Answer (score 0):

When javascript is not working is usually because it was not loaded correctly.

Open your page on Chrome, hit F12 and check the logs for errors.

Hit CTRL-U to see the source code and click on every single `js` and `css` link to see if they are all loaded correctly.

This is an Elfinder example page that works for me in Laravel. Create a view file ONLY with this code and hit it 'online' to see if it works. Sometimes it's just one javascript conflicting with another:

```
<html>
    {{HTML::style('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css', array('media' => 'screen'))}}
    {{HTML::script('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js', array('type' => 'text/javascript'))}}
    {{HTML::script('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js', array('type' => 'text/javascript'))}}
    {{HTML::style('filemanager1/css/elfinder.min.css', array('media' => 'screen'))}}
    {{HTML::script('filemanager1/js/elfinder.min.js', array('type' => 'text/javascript'))}}
    {{HTML::style('filemanager1/css/theme.css', array('media' => 'screen'))}}

    <body>

    Elfinder
    <!-- Element where elFinder will be created (REQUIRED) -->
    <div id="elfinder"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $().ready(function() {
            var elf = $('#elfinder').elfinder({
                // lang: 'ru',             // language (OPTIONAL)
                url : 'filemanager1/php/connector.php'  // connector URL (REQUIRED)
            }).elfinder('instance');            
        });
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Added a part almost got it :D